# Keyboard layout with japanese mozc

Tags: keyboard-layout, 21.10, japanese, mozc

I normally used a US keyboard and mozc for Japanese input - which worked.

Recently I was (unsuccessfully) experimenting to setup a real Japanese keyboard in Ubuntu 21.10. I changed `$HOME/.mozc/ibus_config.textproto` to:

```
    engines {
      name : "mozc-jp"
      longname : "Mozc"
      layout : "ja"
    }
```

After I switched back to my US keyboard, Mozc is still using the Japanese keyboard layout, even after I changed the layout value in `ibus_config.textproto` back to "default" or even to "us". With this layout some characters are missing as I don't have a key in this location (for example the key for <kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>}</kbd>).

[image]

How can I get back to the original configuration?

Comment: Just to confirm, you will not be using the Japanese keyboard going forward? Will you still need to switch between English and 日本語 input?

Comment: @matigo For the moment I want to return to the US keyboard, where I want to use English (and German and French) input plus Japanese input via mozc. To resolve the problems with the Japanese JIS keyboard I will ask another question here later.

Comment: Not sure about how to revert the effect of what you did. But once you figured out, all you need is to install `ibus-mozc` and `mozc-utils-gui`, relogin, and add _Japanese (Mozc)_ as an input source in _Settings_. No need for extra config files.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I followed your advice and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This probably force Mozc to use a particular keyboard layout you choose:

`sudo vi /usr/share/ibus/component/mozc.xml`

Edit

```
...  
<layout>us</layout>
...
```

Save and restart/re-login

---

For normal setting:

`System settings > Text Entry`

[image: Text Entry]
[image: Mozc Keyboard Layout]

Comment: You seem to use another ubuntu version. My file /usr/share/ibus/component/mozc.xml references $HOME/.mozc/ibus_config.textproto for the layout parameter, which is already set to US. And I have no such setting as Text Entry or Input Method Configuration (or I didn't find it).

Comment: Yes, mine is 20.04 based on 16.04 and different Desktop flavor, either. This is a same problem in the other way, written in Japanese https://qiita.com/spumoni/items/f1e5023829c575af4dd0

Comment: Thank you for the link. I am planning to install a fully japanese version of Ubuntu in a virtual machine and I will apply this then. For the moment my problem has been solved by reinstalling the mozc packages as suggested in one of the first comments.

Comment: You're welcome, by the way the minor updates have a lot of troubles and bugs. I am sticking on the major release with LTS only, and sometimes skip problematic one like 18.04 for my main computer. As far as I know 20.04 LTS is very stable one in this decade.